# Feature class to feature class on huge data - iterate loop in ArcGIS pro?

Tags: iterator, loop, arcgis-pro, big-data

I have a very large dataset containing a very large area. I have two files; one that is area specific shapefile and a standalone table that I have joined to the shapefile. Earlier, I have run feature class to feature class to make the join permanent but in this instanse, my computer runs out of memory way before I even get close.

What I want to do, is to make ArcGIS Pro run on smaller areas at a time and collect it all in a permanent file. For example; I have county as another feature and I thought I could do something like this:

Run feature class to feature class on the original file join with the standalone table by county 1 and then make the output, then by county 2, then by county 3 and so on. I think I need to make it run over specific selections but I can't seem to make it run automatically over all the counties and then make it in one big file.

Can anyone help me in understanding how to make this work?

Comment: Please clarify your question: Is county an attribute in the shapefile? what selections are you making?  Could you use objectid to chunk the data instead?  Conceptually you need to make a view of the data using a definition query/selection, join the table and export, then change definition query and append to existing feature class using a field map.

Answer (score 1):

Run a spatial join on your feature class and the counties feature class to collect the county attribute for each of your features.

Put the output into model builder.  Add iterator - iterate feature selection.  Set group by column as counties.

Add feature class to feature class conversion tool. Input the output from the iterator.  Name the output feature class %Value% to name each feature class with county.  Output the feature classes to file GDB.

Make a new model.  Add iterator - feature classes.  Connect the output to the append tool to append all the datasets into one.